# Entity Framework is not generating entity classes

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, odac

- **Entity Framework: 6.4**
- Oracle Managed Data Access: 19.7
- Oracle Managed Data Access Entity Framework: 19.7
- Visual Studio: 2019
- **Oracle database: 11g**

Entity Framework Wizard is working without any problems, but after I click finish, after a couple of seconds of loading I get this:

[image]

Model.tt hasn't generated any clases, and in output window all it says is there have been errors, check the Model.edmx, but those errors are about it failing to generate classes for some views without primary keys, and are errors I get even when it generates the rest of the tables fine.

The error is probably in the database, because it generates the model for an **older version of the schema**. I have tried reinstalling Entity Framework, generating on different machines... One time I dropped some newly added procedures and it managed to generate the model, but the second time, when I reimported the schema and dropped those same procedures again, it failed.

I don't know if anything is different on newer Oracle versions, but working with Entity on 11g has been a pain in the butt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

...

After going through every change between new and old schema, I discovered there are **foreign key** constraints with **different types**, NUMBER(1) and NUMBER(10). I have known from before that EF doesn't support this, so thanks for that.

Why did this had to break the model generation, I don't know. Only if there's was any error reporting...

Comment: congrats! the primary key in edmx is very important you can search for it and why this important

Answer (score 0):

Please try this steps

1. Remove the Entity Framework: 6.4
2. Delete Edmx (Model.edmx)
3. Add new Edmx (Model.edmx) (Assuming you have already connected to database), VS 2019 will automatically add to reference the Entity Framework 5
4. Update the Entity Framework 5 to latest version

Comment: Hey, it's still the same output. I should have mentioned I had tried it on EF 5.0 before, which didn't work. Only this time I've let VS add the EF, as you've said.

Comment: then maybe theres something wrong with the oracle libraries on EF, could please try to check the libraries compability?

Comment: Well Nuget says EF should work with those versions listed above. I had issues with wizard crashing on EF4 and Oracle ODAC 12.xx, but I don't want to got back to version hunting...

Comment: As far as versions go, I am 100% certain it works with current version of libraries on an older schema.